# В чем тут ошибка ? Нужно вывести нечетное число которое больше 20 в Not Weird

Tags: python

Пробовал разные варианты с условиями , но в любом случае выводит **Weird** в последнем условии. А нужно **Not Weird**

```
N = int(input('Ведите целое число..'))
if N % 2 != 0:
    print('Weird')
elif N % 2 == 0 and N >= 2 and N <=5:
    print('Not Weird')
elif N % 2 == 0 and N >= 6 and N <=20:
    print('Weird')
elif N % 2 !=0 and  N > 20:
    print('Not Weird')
```

Comment: переставьте проверки так, как вам надо. по крайней мере последнюю надо переставить выше первой, так как она более строгая.

Comment: Да, благодарю. Так получалось, но условие записано в порядке как указанно в коде. Или же условие и его последовательность не имеет значения, а главное результат ? :)

Comment: У вас логическая ошибка. Чтобы ее понять, временно замените свои принты на вывод разных строчек (типа 1,2,3,4) и поймете, что до 4 условия дело просто не доходит, т.к. оно поглощается первым.